# How to UNCAPPED Data transfer limit via LAN

Tags: lan, data-transfer

I am trying to transfer data between two PC's via LAN cable..and am pretty much successful in doing it..but its transferring data at a speed of only/upto 10 mbps. Is there any way to uncapped this limit to transfer at higher speed. Actually I have a huge data to transfer but at this speed it will take days.
Thank you

EDIT: Please also advise if there is any way to transfer data between two PC's with limited hardware capacity like "NO gigabite eithernet port" at higher speed.
I am suppose to be transferring about 300 Gb data.

Comment: Do you have a 100Mbps or 1Gbps connection to all?

Comment: What type of cable (CAT5/5e/6/7) do you have? What drives (HDD, SSD, ...) are involved on either PC? What’s the status of the LAN connection on either PC (provide screenshots if possible).

Comment: yes cable type is "a priori"

Comment: Also, does your "10 mbps" mean 10 megabits (Mbps) or 10 megabytes (MB/s) per second? For a 100 Mbps "Fast Ethernet" link, 10 MB/s is normal, but 10 Mbps is a problem.

Comment: Hello all, Thanks for your informative response. It seems I have hardware limitation as both of my PC & laptop don't have 1Gbps connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As such, your transfer is never *capped*. What you need to do is to get a FE (Fast Ethernet) or a Gigabit Ethernet network card (you can try USB ones). The speed is limited by your hardware, not software. That said, try changing your cables too, in case you are already using FE. Also, are you sure you mean 10mbps and not 10MBps? This is a common mistake.

Comment: It seems my laptop (Lenovo G500s) & PC don't have FE. And I am not sure of the USB method..so I would appreciate if you can if you can share the USB method with me so that I can try using it. And also the settings that need to be changed if doing via USB.

Comment: Google for USB LAN and you'll find what you need. You can also try searching Amazon eBay etc.

Comment: Thanks. I checked and found it quite costly as I just need to use it a couple of times only.

Comment: can't we transfer data using WIFI via Shareit or anyshare? But I am not sure if it can handle such huge data. Both, my PC connected via wire & laptop via WIFI are on the same WIFI network.

Comment: Wi-Fi speed < Wired LAN speed. This will be faster only in the case that the PC has FE or GbE and the laptop doesn't. Other than that, there is no way to overcome a hardware limitation. Another way I don't think you would want to try is to pull out your laptop HDD and use a 2.5 to 3.5 converter to attach it to your PC SATA. Then you would have the theorotically maxed out speed. Why don't you simply use a usb drive to copy files over? Break up the file into smaller pieces using something like http://www.hjsplit.org/

Comment: Thanks!! But I can't consider any of your suggestions. I definately don't want to pull off my laptops HDD..for sure. and converting a 200GB data into smaller parts is like...Pfff...so another.. no.

Comment: Will go for the LAN data transfer then..it will take some time but I can bear it rather than going messing around with my laptop.